# How to make FunkLoad use gnuplot on windows?

Tags: gnuplot, funkload

I want to use FunkLoad on Windows and I have installed it. I also installed the Windows version of gnuplot.

But when trying to make a report with FunkLoad it gives me :

RuntimeError: Failed to run wgnuplot cmd on C:\path\tests.gplot

What should I do in order for FunkLoad to detect that there is indeed an available gnuplot on the machine to use for the graphs?
Thank you.

Comment: I would bet you need to make sure the path to the Gnuplot executable is on your path. Can you check the contents of your PATH environment variable?

Comment: Great, thank you so much, I guess that was a beginner mistake. You want to put answer instead of comment so I can choose it?

Comment: We all make those mistakes... The only reason I knew what the problem was was that I've made the same mistake over and over and over and over... :-D I added some extra info for anyone who finds this question on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the contents of your PATH variable. On Windows 7, this means "Control Panel"->"System and Security"->"System", in the left bar click "Advanced System Settings", then the "Advanced" tab of the window that opens. At the bottom click "Environment Variables..." then in the "System variables" box, look for the variable named "PATH". Click "Edit" and add the path to your Gnuplot executable to the beginning of the edit box. Make sure you end the path with a semicolon to separate it from the next entry!

PS: To open the Control Panel to the "System" pane, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>.